# How to plot Butterworth filter manually?

Tags: python

I want to ask something about the Butterworth filter in Python.I know that this is how you plot the graph for a Lowpass Butterworth filter:

```
  from scipy import signal
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  b,a=signal.butter(N,fCut,'low',analog=True)
  w,h=signal.freqs(b,a)
  plt.plot(w,(abs(h)))
```

Where N is the order and fCut the cut-off frequency.
But I am having problems trying to do it manually,without using 'signal.freqs'.
This means I have to compute the analog transfer function:
 H(s)=1/Σ(s-sk),k=1..N,sk=e^((j*pi)((2*k+n-1)/2*n))
Is there a way to do this in python?

Comment: Why are you attempting to do this without the tool that does it?

Comment: Are you asking how to compute the Fourier Transform of your filter?

Comment: Well the fourier transform is the analog transfer function.So I think so

Comment: There must be Π instead of Σ and you need to divide s by fCut

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Python code corresponding to the formula:

```
import numpy as np
def butterTF(s, N, fCut):
    sk = np.exp(0.5j*np.pi*(2*np.arange(N) + N + 1)/N)
    return 1/np.multiply.reduce(np.subtract.outer(1.j*s/fCut, sk), axis=1)
```

And to test it:

```
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

b,a=signal.butter(N,fCut,'low',analog=True)
w,h=signal.freqs(b,a)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(w, np.abs(h))
plt.plot(w, np.abs(butterTF(w, N, fCut)), '.')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Some explanation:

Calculating `sk` is straightforward except we need to modify the formula a bit because `np.arange(N)` gives `0, 1, ... , N-1` instead of `1, 2, ... , N`.

Now the tricky part: `np.subtract.outer` forms a matrix `len(s) x N`, whose element `i, k` is the result of `1.j*s[i]/fCut - sk[k]`. May be not a very memory-effective way of calculation, especially if `N` is large, but a relatively fast one.

`np.multiply.reduce(..., axis=1)` calculates the product of each row of the matrix.